# sprintf function: not working in octave the way it does for MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, printf, octave

I need to call another commanline tool using octave .m files as wrapper. In following piece of code, it give eroor in line 'Detector'. It run quite nicely on Matlab but now I need to do it for octave. The documentation of Octave doesn't talk much about multi-line sprintf. Can anybody share solution to deal with such situations.

```
%s =sprintf(...
s =sscanf(...
[...
'                                                                   \n'...
'                                                                   \n'...
'Detector {                                                         \n'...    
'   [Plane: a_x(%f,%f,%f) a_y(%f,%f,%f) center(%f,%f,%f)]           \n'...
'   x1=%f  x2=%f  nx=%d                                             \n'...
'   y1=%f  y2=%f  ny=%d                                             \n'...
'   n_x_sub=%d n_y_sub=%d                                           \n'...        
                                                                                  \n'...
'   %s                                                              \n'...    
'}                                                                  \n'...
'                                                                   \n'...
Beam                                                            \n'...  
'   start(%f,%f,%f)                                                 \n'...
'   %s                                                              \n'...
'   %s                                                              \n'...
'   %s                                                              \n'...
'}                                                                  \n'...
'                                                                   \n'...    
'Commands {                                                         \n'...
'   no_noise                                                        \n'...
'}                                                                  \n'...
],...
eu(1),eu(2),eu(3),...
ev(1),ev(2),ev(3),...
a(1)-d*ew(1),...
a(2)-d*ew(2),...
a(3)-d*ew(3),...
-(uoff+0.5)*par.du,...
(par.nu-uoff-0.5)*par.du,...
par.nu,...
-(voff+0.5)*par.dv,...
(par.nv-voff-0.5)*par.dv,...
par.nv,...
par.up,...
par.up,...
CT_scale,...
a(1),...
a(2),...
a(3),...
keV,...
kV,...
mAs);
```

Comment: Your example code has `sprintf` commented out and is calling `sscanf`, and is missing a couple quotes. Is this the actual code you're running now? And what errors are you getting? Can you include specific error messages?

Comment: Hi Andrew,  In original code sscanf is commented and sprinft is uncommented. This is ERROR:: syntax error

>>> 'Detector {                                                         \n'...

            ^

error: called from:
error:   d:\drasim\useDrasim\src\simulation\generate_projection_data_drasim_imp.
m at line 6, column 10
error:   d:\drasim\useDrasim\fdk\data\simulation\head\generate_projection_data_d
rasim.m at line 35, column 3
error:   d:\drasim\useDrasim\mline\data\simulation\head\call_algorithm.m at line
, colu
mn 0

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities for handling multi-line strings in GNU Octave. Take the following as one of them:

```
sprintf("                     \
This is the first line\n      \
and this is the second\n      \
The square root of %d is %d\n \
", 4, 2)
```

The `\` character is the *string breaker*, you have to use it whenever you desire to continue the string on the next script line.